# How to pass a dynamic list from IronPython to C#

Tags: python, c#, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I want to get a python app to pass a generic list to my C# code. I've created a demo app that duplicates the problem I'm seeing.

I have this python code (Python 2.7), `MainApp.py`, that calls a C# DLL (.NET 4.7):

```py
import clr, sys

sys.path.append(r"C:\PathToMyProject\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug")
clr.AddReference(r"C:\PathToMyProject\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll")

from ClassLibrary1 import Class1

class Person:
    def __init__(self, Name):
        self.Name = Name


myclass = Class1()

nameList = []
nameList.append(Person("Joe"))
nameList.append(Person("Mary"))
nameList.append(Person("Chris"))

result = myclass.SayHello(nameList)

print(result)
```

Notice that I have a list of `Person` objects, `nameList`, that I'm trying to pass. Here's the C# code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string SayHello(List<dynamic> names)
        {
            return $"Hello, {names.Count} people!";
        }
    }
}
```

The `SayHello` method accepts a parameter of `List<dynamic>`. However, I receive the following error when running `>python MainApp.py`:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File ".\MainApp.py", line 20, in
>
> result = myclass.SayHello(nameList) TypeError: No method matches given arguments for SayHello: (<type 'list'>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the following code:

MainApp.py:

```py
import clr, sys

sys.path.append(r"C:\Projects\temp\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug")
clr.AddReference(r"C:\Projects\temp\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll")

from ClassLibrary1 import Class1
from ClassLibrary1 import Person

myclass = Class1()

nameList = []
nameList.append(Person("Joe"))
nameList.append(Person("Mary"))
nameList.append(Person("Chris"))

result = myclass.SayHello(nameList)

print(result)
```

Class1.cs:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string SayHello(dynamic[] names)
        {
            foreach (var item in names)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }

            return $"Hello, {names.Length} people!";
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public Person(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The first thing I did was change the `SayHello` parameter type from `List<dynamic>` to `dynamic[]`.

```
public string SayHello(dynamic[] names)
```

That fixed the type error, but I began receiving a new message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
> memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
> at Python.Runtime.Runtime.PyObject_GetAttrString(IntPtr pointer,
> String name)    at Python.Runtime.PyObject.GetAttr(String name)    at
> Python.Runtime.PyObject.TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, Object&
> result)    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )    at
> System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite
> site, T0 arg0)    at ClassLibrary1.Class1.SayHello(Object[] names) in
> C:\Projects\csharp-nine-cookbook\csharp-nine-cookbook\CSharp9Cookbook\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs:line
> 11    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Python.Runtime.MethodBinder.Invoke(IntPtr inst, IntPtr args, IntPtr
> kw, MethodBase info, MethodInfo[] methodinfo)    at
> Python.Runtime.MethodObject.Invoke(IntPtr target, IntPtr args, IntPtr
> kw, MethodBase info)    at Python.Runtime.MethodBinding.tp_call(IntPtr
> ob, IntPtr args, IntPtr kw)

Apparently IronPython didn't let me pass custom types from python to C#. To fix this, I added a `Person` class to the C# code:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I removed the custom Person class from the python code and referenced the one in the C# code:

```
from ClassLibrary1 import Person
```

Everything worked fine after that.